# Microphone activity level

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, windows-vista

i am trying to detect the microphone activity level. In windows XP, it's returing the activity level.

But in windows vista, even if the mic is not connected it's returning an activity level.

has anyone come across like this.what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I am at work and don't have vista here but, I think there is a setting for that in the audio section. My vista at home always has the mic active. Needless to say its an OS thing not an ActionScript thing